# Adding words from form to url

Tags: forms, url

so I have a little problem. I have a url like this:

> localhost/my/web/plan?dzien=1&mies=4&rok=2015

And it's my form:

```
<form action = "{{ app.request.getRequestUri() }}" method = "get">
    <div class="input_container">
        <input type="text" id="country_id" name="produkt" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
        <ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

When I use it, I get URL like this:

> localhost/my/web/plan?produkt=Makaron

But I want to just add `&produkt=Makaron` to my old URL, to get this:

> localhost/my/web/plan?dzien=1&mies=4&rok=2015&produkt=Makaron

Somebody have idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the current url paremeters to form with hidden input fields.

```
<form action = "{{ app.request.getRequestUri() }}" method = "get">
    <div class="input_container">
        <input type="text" id="country_id" name="produkt" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
        <ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
   <input type="hidden" name = "dzien" value = "{{//a stamemt to get value of this from url}}">
  .....
</form>
```